# finding maximum value from a list which is greater than or equal to another value

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have an date in an input file (say fileA) in the format YYYY-MM-DD

```
e.g. 2016-10-18
```

Now I have a list of date in timestamp format like below in another file (say in fileB)

```
20161017120311
20161017140317
20161018010315
20161018160311
20161019020310
20161019124015
```

Now I want to select only the maximum value of the date (from fileB) which is equal to the date of fileA. So the date which will be selected from fileB in this case will be `20161018160311`.

It can also happen that there is no record in fileB for date `20161018`. Say fileB looks like below

```
20161017120311
20161017140317
20161019020310
20161019124015
20161020010315
20161021160311
```

In the case the same code should select the maximum value of the just next available date. i.e. next available date is `20161019` and the maximum value for `20161019` is `20161019124015`. So the output should be in this case  `20161019124015`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

maxDate.sh:

```
fileA=$1
fileB=$2
date=`sed s/-//g $fileA`
max=`grep $date $fileB | sort | tail -1`
if [[ $max == '' ]];
then
    date=`sed s/-//g $fileA $fileB | sort | grep $date -1 | tail -1 | egrep -o [0-9]{8}`; 
    max=`grep $date $fileB | sort | tail -1`
fi
echo $max
```

Running:

```
./maxDate.sh fileA fileB
```

Comment: Can you please change the code snippet to read it from files, like fileA and fileB

Comment: For robustness, please double-quote your variable references, such as `"$fileA"`. Consider using the more modern command substitution syntax, `$(...)` instead of backticks.
Since the question is generically tagged `shell`, it's better to avoid Bashisms such as `[[ … ]]`. Using about 15 child processes that read the input file multiple times to accomplish the 
task is quite inefficient.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit how the statement is picking up the next date `date=`sed s/-//g $fileA $fileB | sort | grep $date -1 | tail -1 | egrep -o [0-9]{8}`;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **`awk` command**, which is much more efficient than [Marcel Jacques Machado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40121731/45375):

```
#!/bin/sh

fileA='/path/to/file A'
fileB='/path/to/file B'

awk -v refDate="$(tr -d '-' < "$fileA")" '
  substr($0, 1, length(refDate)) < refDate { next } # skip lines before
  substr($0, 1, length(refDate)) == refDate { lastMatch = $0; next } # save match
  { exit } # we are done once the first greater row is reached 
  END { print (lastMatch == "" ? $0 : lastMatch); exit } # print last match or current row
' "$fileB"
```

This creates *2* child processes - one for the command substitution involving `tr`, and one for `awk` - in contrast with the estimated up to *15* child processes that Marcel's solution creates, which potentially read the input file multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat program.awk
NR==FNR {                    # get the date from the first file
    a=$0"000000"             # zeropad the end (a="2016-10-18000000")
    gsub(/-/,"",a)           # remove dashes (a="20161018000000")
    next                 
} 
$0 >= a {                    # we sorted fileB so the next bigger or equal to a is the date
    if(b=="")                # pick whatever is the next date for reference
        b=substr($0,1,8)     # just the date part
    d=substr($0,1,8)         # get this records date part
    if (d>b) {               # if this date is bigger than the reference...
        print c; exit        # output and exit
    } 
    c=$0                     # the latest timestamp on this date
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk fileA <(sort -n fileB)
20161019124015
```